# Changing attribute before attr_encrypted encrypts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, attr

I am trying to figure out how to change an attribute before [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor) does its encrypting.

I want to remove dashes from a number before I save it to a database encrypted.

```
attr_encrypted :ssn, key: Rails.application.secrets.secret_encrypt_key
validates :ssn, format: { with: /\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}/,
                          message: "SSN must be separated by dashes" },
                allow_nil: true
validates :ssn, length: { is: 11 }, allow_nil: true

before_save :format_ssn

def format_ssn
  return if ssn.nil?
  ssn.delete!("-")
end
```

This is what I currently have. It does not work in the rails console. I can't for the life of me think of how else to accomplish this. I was trying to use a setter originally but attr_encrypted would no longer do its magic if I did that. I'm assuming that is because attr_encrypted itself is reusing the setter.

Any suggestions on how to format before attr_encrypted encrypts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried `before_validation`?

Comment: Thanks I did try before_validation and had the same issue. i believe it was because of what I was doing inside the callback method. I think i had to set it to self.ssn to get the changes to stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

Doing:

```
  def format_ssn
    return if ssn.nil?
    self.ssn = ssn.delete!("-")
  end
```

solves the issue